# Как сделать кастомную инициализацию UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Обычно делаю инициализацию кнопки через

`UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Необходимо избавиться от повторяющихся строк, для этого хочу сделать кастомную инициализацию через метод

`- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}`

Возможно ли проинициализировать кнопку через `buttonType`, в методе `init` ??

Comment: вам надо чтобы было что то типа `[UIButton customButton]` который вернет вам инстанс кнопки?

Comment: Что то например `UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithCustomButton]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо создать категорию для UIButton и там создать новый метод.

1) сначала создаете новый objective-C файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) объявить, что это будет категория для UIButton

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) написать код для создания

.h

```
@interface UIButton (CustomInits)

+ (instancetype)buttonWithTypeCustom;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "UIButton+CustomInits.h"

@implementation UIButton (CustomInits)

+ (instancetype)buttonWithTypeCustom
{
    return [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
}

@end
```

4) импортировать категорию и создавать кнопки

```
UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithTypeCustom];
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большее !!